# Angular *ngIf good practice (HTML / TS)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

For a very long time I have been using Angular's condition a lot in my HTML pages:

```
<p *ngIf="var === true">Test</p>
```

(for example)

Except that on some pages I have *ngIf with dozens of checks to do (which are sometimes even used on several tags in the same page)

```
<p *ngIf="var1 === true && var2 === true && var3 === true && var4 === true && var5 === true && var6 === true && var7 === true && var8 = == true && var9 === true && var10 === true">Test</p>
```

(for example)

So I just modified this by:

```
<p *ngIf="this.isVarsTrue()">Test</p>
```

and in my TS page

```
isVarsTrue () {
    if (var1 === true && var2 === true && var3 === true && var4 === true && var5 === true && var6 === true && var7 === true && var8 === true && var9 === true && var10 === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

However, by adding a console log in this method I see that it is called a lot of times (5 times for each action on the page near ready) and I therefore wondered if this was a good practice or not.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The inline version is also called multiple times so there's no difference. And calling a simple function like this 5 times is literally nothing. (Also, you can just `return var1 === true && ...` there's rarely if ever any point in `if(condition) return true; else return false;`)

Comment: if you want to say that some is true generally I use simple:, e.g. `*ngIf="var1 && var2 && var3"`. -Yes, I know that if the value of var1 is "hello", the condition is true, but nobody makes my variable get the value "hello" :)-. About your question, there's no diference of perfomance. I like "in-line" for clarifly. NOTE: Try order the variable, less probably get the value "true", before than other one

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it's nice, I see it now more clearly! :)

Answer (score 3):

It because of how Angular change detection work when you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` which every component use by default (unless you change it). I would say, that is not a huge cost to check if couple conditions are met (unless you have complicated logic and your application is fast enough). What you could do, is to change `ChangeDetectionStrategy` or store result of this condition in some variable and recalculate it if needed.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment stated, there is little difference in performance when using a simple function like you gave, and it may even be beneficial because you said it is being used in multiple places. Every event on your screen will fire off your checks whether it is in the HTML or in the typescript. As a rule for myself, I keep function calls out of any HTML files (except for special events like click or change events) to stop myself from doing something stupid and making my app super laggy.

Here is a general list of what types of functions I personally consider safe/unsafe from calling in the HTML:

**Doesn't matter if you call these types of functions from HTML**

- boolean/object/string/number/etc. checks
- simple if statements

**DO NOT call these types of functions from HTML**

- Iterating over an array
- Observable/Subject/Promise calls
- Server calls
- Timeouts/waits

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it's nice, I see it now more clearly! :)

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case I don't think it will actually damage performance.

However, in order to not execute the same code in every render, I suggest creating a new component boolean variable that only gets updated when your multiple variables change. It's more readable and prevents you from executing code in case that function starts to get more complex

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it's nice, I see it now more clearly! :)